# How can I get the Planet Progression mod for Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

How do I get the Planet Progression mod for Minecraft 1.11.2? It keeps giving me a crash report! Here's the crash report.

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----

WARNING: coremods are present:
  MicdoodlePlugin (MicdoodleCore-1.11.2.jar)
Contact their authors BEFORE contacting forge

// This is a token for 1 free hug. Redeem at your nearest Mojangsta: [~~HUG~~]

Time: 3/14/19 10:04 AM
Description: There was a severe problem during mod loading that has caused the game to fail

net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoaderExceptionModCrash: Caught exception from Yet Another Food Mod (yafm)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: airbreather/mods/airbreathercore/mod/IModule
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.FMLModContainer.constructMod(FMLModContainer.java:552)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:253)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:231)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:148)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Loader.loadMods(Loader.java:582)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.beginMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:233)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71384_a(Minecraft.java:440)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:352)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: airbreather.mods.airbreathercore.mod.IModule
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:191)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:182)
    ... 37 more


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.11.2
    Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
    Java Version: 1.8.0_51, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 560153848 bytes (534 MB) / 771751936 bytes (736 MB) up to 2147483648 bytes (2048 MB)
    JVM Flags: 8 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx2G -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    FML: MCP 9.38 Powered by Forge 13.20.1.2588 20 mods loaded, 20 mods active
    States: 'U' = Unloaded 'L' = Loaded 'C' = Constructed 'H' = Pre-initialized 'I' = Initialized 'J' = Post-initialized 'A' = Available 'D' = Disabled 'E' = Errored
    UC  minecraft{1.11.2} [Minecraft] (minecraft.jar) 
    UC  mcp{9.19} [Minecraft Coder Pack] (minecraft.jar) 
    UC  FML{8.0.99.99} [Forge Mod Loader] (forge-1.11.2-13.20.1.2588.jar) 
    UC  forge{13.20.1.2588} [Minecraft Forge] (forge-1.11.2-13.20.1.2588.jar) 
    UC  Micdoodlecore{} [Micdoodle8 Core] (minecraft.jar) 
    UC  mercurius_updater{1.0} [mercurius_updater] (MercuriusUpdater-1.11.2.jar) 
    UC  xray{1.3.3} [XRay] (Advanced-XRay-Mod-1.11.2.jar) 
    UC  croparia{1.14.1} [Croparia] (Croparia-Mod-1.11.2.jar) 
    UC  galacticraftcore{4.0.1.121} [Galacticraft Core] (Galacticraft-Mod-1.11.2.jar) 
    UC  galacticraftplanets{4.0.1.121} [Galacticraft Planets] (Galacticraft-Planets-Mod-1.11.2.jar) 
    UC  mjrlegendslib{1.11.2-1.0.3} [MJRLegendsLib] (MJRLegendsLib-1.11.2.jar) 
    UC  extraplanets{1.11.2-0.5.5} [Extra Planets] (Extra-Planets-Mod-1.11.2.jar) 
    UC  eyemod{1.0.0} [EyeMod] (EyeMod-Mod-1.11.2.jar) 
    UC  guideapi{1.11.2-2.1.4-56} [Guide-API] (Guide-API-1.11.2.jar) 
    UC  imsm{2.0} [Instant Massive Structures Mod] (Instant-Massive-Structures-Mod-1.11.2.jar) 
    UC  jei{4.5.1.296} [Just Enough Items] (JEI-1.11.2.jar) 
    UC  simpleportals{1.11.2-1.4.0.0} [Simple Portals] (Simple-Portals-Mod-1.11.2.jar) 
    UC  xaeroworldmap{1.2.5} [Xaero's World Map] (XaerosWorldMap_1.2.5_Forge_1.11.jar) 
    UE  yafm{1.0} [Yet Another Food Mod] (Yet-Another-Food-Mod-1.11.2.jar) 
    UC  zeiyocraft{0.8.1} [ZeiyoCraft] (ZeiyoCraft-Mod-1.11.2.jar) 
    Loaded coremods (and transformers): 
MicdoodlePlugin (MicdoodleCore-1.11.2.jar)
  micdoodle8.mods.miccore.MicdoodleTransformer
    GL info: ' Vendor: 'Intel' Version: '4.5.0 - Build 23.20.16.4973' Renderer: 'Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620'
```

Comment: This post doesn't show a lot of effort. What have you tried? What went wrong?

Comment: Its giving me a crash report.

Comment: can you please edit the question with the crash report in it?

Comment: We don't help with getting modded Minecraft working, I'm afraid. There's just too much that can go wrong with mod interactions for it to be feasible.

Comment: Why was this closed as a game recommendation as opposed to a custom modded minecraft close reason?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

## How to install Planet Progression Mod for 1.11.2 with Forge Modloader

> 1. Download Forge Installer, Galacticraft 4, MJRLegendsLib
> 2. Right click, Run as Administrator and press ok to install Forge. (You can skip this step if you have installed Minecraft Forge)
> 3. Open start on desktop > open run (Or you can use the Windows + R keyboard shortcut)
> 4. Type %appdata% into Run and press enter
> 5. Go to folder /.minecraft/mods
> 6. Put the .jar file you have downloaded into mods folder and then run minecraft. Done!

Comment: Thanks. But its still not working.

Comment: Do you have the Forge installer?

Comment: Yes i do have it.

Comment: Also, do you have Galacticraft? Just to make sure... It is an add on for Galacticraft...

Comment: I do have that as well.

Comment: It works for 1.12.2 but, it crashes when i go to space. I want 1.11.2 though.